# Can I travel to Germany with my Romanian wife?

Tags: visas, germany, paperwork, family, spouses

Can I travel to germany with my romanian wife without a visa? I also have a Romanian family residency card.

Comment: What is your nationality? How long are you travelling to Germany for, and for what purpose (e.g., tourism, business, etc.)?

Comment: @DavidRicherby If staying for max 90 days, OP doesn't need a visa

Comment: How is this question unclear? OP has a  Romanian Family member card

Answer (score 3):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a family member
>   residence card issued by Romania. The card must be issued to family members of a
>     national of Switzerland or an EEA Member State.
>     They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days and must
>     travel with or travel to join the national of Switzerland or
>     EEA Member State. This does not apply to passengers with a
>     different type of residence Permit.

So if travelling with your wife and staying for max 90 days, you do **not** need a visa.

Show your passport and family residence card at German border control.